# For Loop with Append issue

Tags: r, for-loop, append, time-series

I'm having trouble using append in a for loop.  The goal of the for loop below is to take the ModelCast$mean and append 3 more forecast$mean on to it.  So in the end length(append_cast) = 40.  Instead I'm getting a length(append_cast) = 20.  I think the problem is that append is only being run once.

The earlier code outside the for loop trains and forecasts a model. The rest of the code in the for loop is to fit that model to 3 new chunks of data.

This is inspired by Rob Hyndman's blog post:
http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/

specifically the part on Multi-step forecasts without re-estimation

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
library("forecast")
library("tseries")
library("sqldf")
library("manipulate")
library("caret")
library("qdapTools")
library("RODBC")
library("dplyr")
library("yts")


##Partitioning Time Series
EndLearn1<-length(tsData-3*10)
data_tsLearn1 <-tsData[1:EndLearn1] 

##Fit Model 
fit_Model <- auto.arima(data_tsLearn1)

##Forecast Model 1st time
ModelCast<-forecast(fit_Model, h=10)

for(i in 1:3)
{  
  startLearn2<-1+i*10
  EndLearn2<-EndLearn1+i*10

  y <- tsData[startLearn2:EndLearn2] 
  fit_new <- Arima(y, model=fit_Model )

  append_cast <- append(ModelCast$mean,forecast(fit_new, h=10)$mean, after=i*10) ## Only seems to append one forecast instead of 3
}


Update: The change to the code below works
append_cast <- ts()


for(i in 1:3)
{  
 startLearn2<-1+i*10
 EndLearn2<-EndLearn1+i*10-1

 y <- tsData[startLearn2:EndLearn2] 
 fit_new <- Arima(y, model=fit_Model )

 append_cast <- append(append_cast, forecast(fit_new, h=10)$mean,   after=i*10)
 append_final<-ts(append(ModelCast$mean,append_cast[2:length(append_cast)]))    ## First value in append_cast is na because ts() starts that way
}

Data:
dput(tsData[1:300])
c(7.6, 0.6, 2.2, 1.8, NA, 6.6, 12.8, 0.2, 5.6, 2, NA, 0.4, NA, 
1.6, 0.8, 2, 0.4, NA, NA, 2, 4.8, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, NA, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 20, 27.4, 0.4, 29.2, 30.4, 
0.2, 42.2, NA, 0.8, 0.2, 2, 32.2, 2.4, 7, 2.2, 30.8, 26.6, 15.2, 
12, 10.2, 27, 15.8, 22.2, 20, 23.8, 1, 18.2, 6, 23, 16.2, 17, 
1.8, 17.8, 8.8, 0.2, 7.8, 2.6, 0.2, 17.8, 2.4, 15.4, 3.2, 8, 
12.4, 3.2, NA, 3.2, 2.2, 5.6, NA, 0.4, 2.6, 1.8, 2.4, NA, 2.2, 
NA, 1.6, NA, NA, NA, 1.4, 1.8, 0.2, NA, 1.8, NA, 1.4, 1.6, 5, 
0.2, NA, NA, 1.4, 0.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.8, 
3, 0.2, 11.4, 13.2, 15, 13.2, 5.8, 6.8, 24.6, 17, 21.6, 5, 11.4, 
23, 9.2, 7.2, 12, 31.6, 43, 1.2, 38.2, 38.4, 15.2, 43.6, 29.6, 
20, 3.8, 23, 3.2, 15.4, 14.6, 17.4, 27.6, 24, 27.8, 35.4, 2.4, 
12.4, 36, NA, 0.2, 15.6, 0.4, 20.8, 3.4, 22.8, 23.8, 25.6, 34, 
NA, 0.6, 5.6, 1.8, NA, NA, 28.6, NA, NA, 40.4, NA, 16.2, 13, 
4, NA, NA, 1.6, 1.2, 6, NA, 1.6, 1.2, NA, 1.8, NA, NA, 0.4, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4, NA, NA, 0.8, 3.4, 
3.2, 3.2, 3.8, 4.4, 2.8, 5.2, 11, 10.8, 0.2, 1.8, 2.4, 4.4, 2, 
1.2, 1.8, 4.6, 6, 5, 8.6, 10.6, 10.4, 10, 7.2, 7.6, 0.2, 17, 
3, 2.6, 1.4, 2.8, 0.2, NA, 7.4, 17.4, 7.4, 0.6, NA, 5.2, 1.6, 
NA, 7.2, 2.6, 7.2, 7.6, 15, 21.8, NA, 2, NA, 10.4, 4, 2.4, 4.8, 
1.4, NA, NA, 0.6, NA, 1.2, 0.2, NA, 1.4, 3, 0.4, 1, NA, 1.6, 
38.8, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, 1.8, 2.8, 
4.2, 1.6, 7.4, 2, 6, 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `append` function expects you to pass it the thing you want to append *to* as well as what you want to append to it. You're only passing the latter. I sussed this out by (don't tell anyone) reading the documentation for append.

The other things you'll need are to initialize the vector `append_Cast` so that it will be there to append to on the first loop. And you will need to wrap your values you want to append into a `c()` wrapper so they will be a vector. Something like this:

```
 append_cast <- {}

  for(i in 1:3)
  {  
    i<-1
    startLearn2<-1+i*10
    EndLearn2<-EndLearn1+i*10

    y <- tsData[startLearn2:EndLearn2] 
    fit_new <- Arima(y, model=fit_Model )

    append_cast <- append(append_cast, c(ModelCast$mean,forecast(fit_new, h=10)$mean, after=i*10)) ## Only seems to append one forecast instead of 3
  }
```

Comment: Thanks your tip got me pretty close.  I had to make a couple changes, they're in the update in the code above.  In your version of the code you wind up with append_cast of length 60 because you're also appending ModelCast$mean on each time.  Also I initialized append_cast as a time-series instead of a vector.